# Is there a way to check if Shopware6 Twig Template is running in DEV mode?

Tags: environment-variables, twig, shopware, shopware6

In order to ouput special debug information, I'd like to only show it in the template if the shop is running in DEV mode.

I tried to read the ENV Variable without any success:

```
{{ app.request.server.get('APP_ENV') }}
```

Or is something like this possible?

```
{{ app.appVariable.get('environment') }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `app.environment`

```
{% set isDebug = app.environment == 'dev' %}
```